Using Google ML Kit's Smart Reply plugin in flutter chat app
I am trying to implement  Smart Reply functionality in my flutter app using Google's ML Kit.
But I am getting an error in this part of the code-
void _generateSmartReplies() async {
  final messageText = _messageController.text;
  final timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

  // Add message to the conversation context
  _smartReply.addMessageToConversationFromLocalUser(messageText, timestamp);

  // Fetch smart replies based on the updated conversation context
  final response = await _smartReply.suggestReplies();

  setState(() {
   
    _smartReplies = response.suggestions.map((suggestion) => suggestion.getText()).toList();
  });
}

The error is:

The method 'getText' isn't defined for the type 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'getText'.

what to do?
This is the entire code:
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:ca/Addons/chat_bubble.dart';
import 'package:ca/models/auth_gate.dart';
import 'package:google_ml_kit/google_ml_kit.dart';
import 'package:ca/models/chatservice.dart';
import 'package:google_mlkit_smart_reply/google_mlkit_smart_reply.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String recieverEmail;
  final String recieverId;

  ChatScreen(
      {super.key, required this.recieverEmail, required this.recieverId});

  @override
  State<ChatScreen> createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();
  final Chatservice _chatService = Chatservice();
  FocusNode myfocusNode = FocusNode();
  final SmartReply _smartReply =SmartReply();

  List<String> _smartReplies = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    myfocusNode.addListener(() {
      if (myfocusNode.hasFocus) {
        Future.delayed(
          const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          () => scrollDown(),
        );
      }
    });

    Future.delayed(
      const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      () => scrollDown(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myfocusNode.dispose();
    _messageController.dispose();
    _smartReply.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  void scrollDown() {
    _scrollController.animateTo(
      _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    );
  }

  void _sendMessage() async {
    if (_messageController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      await _chatService.sendMessage(
          widget.recieverId, _messageController.text);
      _messageController.clear();
      _generateSmartReplies();
    }
    scrollDown();
  }

void _generateSmartReplies() async {
  final messageText = _messageController.text;
  final timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

  // Add message to the conversation context
  _smartReply.addMessageToConversationFromLocalUser(messageText, timestamp);

  // Fetch smart replies based on the updated conversation context
  final response = await _smartReply.suggestReplies();

  setState(() {
    
    _smartReplies = response.suggestions.map((suggestion) => suggestion.getText()).toList();
  });
}





  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          widget.recieverEmail,
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .titleLarge!
              .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Get.changeThemeMode(
                  Get.isDarkMode ? ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.dark);
            },
            icon: Icon(
              Get.isDarkMode ? Icons.dark_mode : Icons.light_mode,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: _buildMessageList(),
          ),
          _buildSmartReplies(),
          _buildUserInput(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMessageList() {
    String senderID = getCurrentUser()!.uid;
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _chatService.getMessages(widget.recieverId, senderID),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text("error");
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Text("Loading");
        }
        return ListView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          children:
              snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) => _buildMessageItem(doc)).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMessageItem(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    bool isCurrentUser = data["senderID"] == getCurrentUser()!.uid;
    var alignment =
        isCurrentUser ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft;

    return Container(
      alignment: alignment,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment:
            isCurrentUser ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          ChatBubble(message: data["message"], iscurrentUser: isCurrentUser),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildUserInput() {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: TextField(
            controller: _messageController,
            focusNode: myfocusNode,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter your message...',
              hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1.0),
              ),
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.send),
          onPressed: _sendMessage,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSmartReplies() {
    return _smartReplies.isNotEmpty
        ? Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
            color: Colors.grey[200],
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                children: _smartReplies.map((reply) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      _messageController.text = reply;
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 6.0, horizontal: 12.0),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        reply,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          )
        : Container();
  }
}


The error occurs because "response.suggestions" is a List of Strings. In other words, each item in "response.suggestions" is already a String, so there is no "getText" method for a String. To fix this, you can directly add all items from "response.suggestions" to your list without mapping them. You can do it like this:
_smartReplies.addAll(response.suggestions);

